# Наследование переменных в C#

Tags: c#

У меня есть 2 класса, в одном переменная создается, в другом она должна использоваться, но во 2 классе он ее считает несуществующей.
Как сделать чтобы одну переменную заданную в одном классе, можно было использовать в остальных?
Язык C#

Comment: Переменная не создаётся в классе. Она создаётся в методе, а в классе определяются поля (и не только).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через наследование.

Answer (score 4):

Не нужно использовать поля одного класса в другом. Значительно полезнее сделать поле закрытым и добавить в класс `A` метод, который будет использовать внутреннее поле и делать что-то полезное/осмысленное, нужное классу `B`.

Это называется инкапсуляцией и позволяет изменять в будущем внутреннее представление класса `A`, не ломая всех своих клиентов, включая класса `B`.

В некоторых случаях, нужны именно результат работы класса `A`, в этом случае опять лучше объявить метод в классе `A`, который будет делать осмысленную работу и возвращать результат своим клиентам:

```
public class A
{
   public Result DoSomethingUseful()
   {
      // Делаем что-то полезное
   }
}

public class B
{
  public void Foo(A a)
  {
    // Не залазим во внутреннее представление класса А,
    // посылаем ему сообщение и получаем результат:
    var result a.DoSomethingUseful();
    // ОБрабатываем результат
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Быстрый, простой ответ: Public?

Comment: public static bool weapon_active=false;

Comment: И не работает

Comment: А как вы к ней обращаетесь?